# problem with series in this proof

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, matrix-calculus

I am studying exponential matrices ,  and there is a part of a proof that I don't understand .

Given the matrix
$$
J=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1 \\
-1 & 0
\end{array}\right)
$$
the power of $J$ are eas to compute
$$
J^{2 k}=(-1)^k I, J^{2 k+1}=(-1)^k J
$$
and so
$$
\begin{aligned}
e^{\beta_j J t} & =\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} \frac{\beta_j^k J^k t^k}{k !} \\
& =\left(\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^k\left(\beta_j t\right)^{2 k}}{(2 k) !}\right) I+\left(\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^k\left(\beta_j t\right)^{2 k+1}}{(2 k+1) !}\right) J \\
& =\cos \left(\beta_j t\right) I+\sin \left(\beta_j t\right) J=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\cos \left(\beta_j t\right) & \sin \left(\beta_j t\right) \\
-\sin \left(\beta_j t\right) & \cos \left(\beta_j t\right)
\end{array}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

The part that I don't understand is when he separate the infinite summation in 2 parts . I Don't know why is possible to do that ,in general you can't separate an infinite series .

Comment: In general no. However, if you can show the series is absolutely convergent, you can split it and rearrange it however you like.

Comment: Separating the series and rearranging it are not quite the same thing. [Apostol, ch. 8](https://www.amazon.com/Mathematical-Analysis-Second-Tom-Apostol/dp/0201002884) has a very good treatment of this.

Comment: @eyeballfrog really thanks this is what I needed

Comment: @Matematleta Really thanks I will take a look